# matching 1st character if matched delete entire line

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

If 1st character found 0 or 1 entire line should be filter out, however if 0 or 1 found anywhere else in the line no action should be taken. Also if some number staring with 1 like 12, 110, 185 should not be filter out.

For example

```
0    rdrk2v   rdrk2v   daily_ux   mediark4p 06/24/2013 04:29:02 
1    rdrk2v   rdrk2v   daily_ux   mediark4p 06/24/2013 04:29:02 
150  svrk2    svrk2    daily_ux   mediark2p 06/24/2013 05:52:15 
71   rdrk1p   std_11   daily_ux   mediark1p 06/24/2013 02:23:25 
196  evrk1p   std_110  daily_ux   masterrk1 06/24/2013 03:00:00
```

1st and 2nd line should be filter out and the txt file should contain only

```
150  svrk2    svrk2    daily_ux   mediark2p 06/24/2013 05:52:15 
71   rdrk1p   std_11   daily_ux   mediark1p 06/24/2013 02:23:25 
196  evrk1p   std_110  daily_ux   masterrk1 06/24/2013 03:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `findstr` and it's Regex capability:

```
>type file
0    rdrk2v   rdrk2v   daily_ux   mediark4p 06/24/2013 04:29:02
1    rdrk2v   rdrk2v   daily_ux   mediark4p 06/24/2013 04:29:02
150  svrk2    svrk2    daily_ux   mediark2p 06/24/2013 05:52:15
71   rdrk1p   std_11   daily_ux   mediark1p 06/24/2013 02:23:25
196  evrk1p   std_110  daily_ux   masterrk1 06/24/2013 03:00:00

>findstr /v "^[01][^0-9]" file
150  svrk2    svrk2    daily_ux   mediark2p 06/24/2013 05:52:15
71   rdrk1p   std_11   daily_ux   mediark1p 06/24/2013 02:23:25
196  evrk1p   std_110  daily_ux   masterrk1 06/24/2013 03:00:00
```